# Cannot Open Include File: 'QtSql'

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to connect to a SQLITE database.

I have a class, SQLConnector, which includes QtSql and QSqlDatabase.  I have `QT = core gui sql`  in my .pro file.  I've included the code just in case.  Does anyone know why I am getting the "C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtSql': No such file or directory" error? I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, and rerunning qmake, to no avail.

Thanks for your time.

sqlconnector.h:

```
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlDatabase>

class SQLConnector
{
    SQLConnector();
    int connectToLite();
}
```

sqlconnector.cpp:

```
#include "sqlconnector.h"

SQLConnector::SQLConnector() {}

int SQLConnector::connectToLite()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setUserName("");
    db.setPassword("");
    db.setDatabaseName("C:\\Users\\My Name\\Desktop\\localDatabase");

    bool ok = db.open();
    if(ok) qDebug() << db.lastError.text();
    else   qDebug() << "Connected to database no problem.";
}
```

newEditor.pro:

```
QT = core gui sql
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -=app_bundle

SOURCES += main.cpp \
     sqlconnector.cpp

HEADERS += \
    sqlconnector.h
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "sqlconnector.h"

int main() 
{
    SQLConnector connector();
    connector.connectToLite();
}
```

Comment: In the project file you wrote: `HEADERS += sqlconnector.cpp`, but should be `HEADERS += sqlconnector.h`

Comment: Thanks, that was just a typo.  I switched it.

Comment: What happens if you remove `#include <QtSql>`?

Comment: @szx It then switches the error to QSqlDatabase.  If I comment both out, it starts yelling at me in my connectToLite() method because it doens't know what a QSqlDatabas is.

Comment: @user2761933: Maybe it's `<QtSql/QSqlDatabase>`?

Comment: If I type in `<QtSql/` it does offer `<QtSql/QSqlDatabase>` as an autofill option.  But even if I take it up on the offer it still says there is no such file or directory.